# Determining if a process is a child or parent process (not using return value of fork)

Tags: c, linux, fork

How to write a programm to show whether it's a child or parent process after the `fork()` is used?

I need to find other way then checking the return value of `fork()` or `getpid()` function.

I know e.g. that process resource utilizations (`getrusage(2)`) and CPU time counters (`times(2)`) are reset to zero in the child. How i can use for example that knowledge (or other child-parents differences) to determine my problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why? What is wrong with using the return value from `fork`?

Comment: My exercise is to find three ways of determining if a process is a child or a parent. I already used return value of `fork` and `getpid`. Now i need to find a third solution.

Comment: Get the process ID before the fork and afterwards. Compare

Comment: That I have already done. That's my second solution.

Comment: Use `getppid` instead

Comment: I thought about that, but wouldn't it be too similar? There is no other option?

Comment: Too similar? Get the parent process ID before the fork and use getppid afterwards. If you are the child this changes. Otherwise it stays the same

Comment: most processes are child of some other process (e.g. a shell).

Answer (score 1):

- Setup a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` in one of the processes and end the other one. If the `SIGCHLD` handler gets called you know the child died. If not the parent died.
- Another (less distructive) way it to call `wait()`. If it returns `ECHLD` no child is around, thus the calling process is the child. If it blocks, at least one child is around, thus the calling process is the parent.
- Or call `waitpid()` with PID of the other process. The same logic on the result as for `wait()` applies.

Answer (score 0):

You could exploit the fact that the parent will be a process group leader (and thus its pid will be the same as its process group id) while the child will be a member of that process group and thus its pid will be different from the process group id:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *self = NULL;

    fork(); /* looking at return value would be cheating */
    int pid = getpid();
    int pgid = getpgid(0);

    if (pid == pgid)
        self = "Parent";
    else
        self = "Child";

    printf("%s pid = %d pgid = %d\n", self, pid, pgid);
}
```

Running yields:

```
$ ./pgid
Parent pid = 29400 pgid = 29400
Child pid = 29401 pgid = 29400
```

This does of course still use `getpid()` but not in the same way you describe above.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you might also use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). The process of pid 1234 is described by the directory `/proc/1234/` and you could read sequentially and parse the `/proc/1234/status` pseudo-file to get all that information.

To understand a bit more, read the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page, then type

```
 cat /proc/self/status
 cat /proc/$$/status
 cat /proc/self/maps
 cat /proc/$$/maps
```

in a terminal, and try to understand the output. You might parse it programmatically (e.g. with  `FILE*f = fopen("/proc/1234/status","r");` then do some `fgets` or `fscanf` on `f`; then `fclose(f);`)